# Phpstorm, windows and subversion. Checking out a file with : in its name

Tags: svn, phpstorm

So I just joined a new company, and am trying to check out a branch to my computer. Problem is, one of the files is titled essentially why::god::why.abc

While thats fine on linux, windows doesnt like that, and phpstorm is giving an error when trying to checkout the branch when it gets to that point, and wont let me continue past it.

Honestly, I have no need to work on that file, and can just ignore it. Things is, I go to file->settings->version controll->ignore list and add the entire directory tree where the file is in (there are only about 6 files in that directory tree, and atm i really dont need any of them) but it keeps failing with the same file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Windows, and Windows does not allow files to have `:` in their name. This has nothing to do with Subversion or PHPStorm itself. It's strictly a Windows issue.

The only thing you can do is rename the offending file to remove the colon, or use an OS that allows colons in file names such as Linux or Mac OS X.

To rename the file, use the `svn move` command:

```
C:\> set REPO=http://svnhost/svn
C:\> svn move %REPO%/trunk/path/to/bad/file/foo:bar %REPO%/truck/path/to/bad/file/foo_bar
```

If you have your editor set, you should be able to create a commit message and rename the file this way. If not, add the `-m"commit message"` to the command. If the URL doesn't like the colon in the name, you may have to resort to using *url-encoding* by replacing the colon with a `%3A`:

```
C:\> set REPO=http://svnhost/svn
C:\> svn move %REPO%/trunk/path/to/bad/file/foo%3Abar %REPO%/truck/path/to/bad/file/foo_bar
```

Comment: Yeah, talking with my manager it appears there really is no way around it, as I can't do an svn move on the files, the company allows us to use any linux distro we want, but if we do we're out of luck for any support from our IT office (which I don't really get considering our app runs on ubuntu... but w/e) and I hate Mac (no offense to anyone who likes it)

So what Im just going to do is all the svn stuff via command line on my Lab VM, and just do a synchronized deployement with PHP storm, which will allow me to skip the : files. It's slower, and not ideal, but will work fine.

Comment: You can try VirtualBox and then install Ubuntu on it. If IT gives you Mac support, get a Mac. Install VirtualBox on the Mac and run Windows. Do 90% of your work in the Windows VM on the Mac. The Mac is very good at running Windows under a VM. Then, when you have these _Windows issues_, you can switch to the Mac command line. I take it your hatred for Mac is the OS. You won't be using it in this scenario. You'll do Windows and the Unix command line.

Comment: I appreciate it, but my hatred for Mac is not just the OS, it is quite literally everything. I hate how they cost **double** the price than a comparable PC, that their entire marketing strategy is "ohhh shiny", the entire culture behind it, everything. I despise macs.

Comment: Double the price? You haven't priced *Ultrabooks*. True, you can find a laptop by Dell or HP for $300, but if you look at the *Ultrabooks*, you'll see they're between $800 to $2000. And, if you add the same processor and memory as a Mac, you'll find they're pretty much the same price. The double the cost was true in the 1990s, but not today. I just priced out a Dell Latitude E5430 at $1433. Compatible MacBook Pro is $1299.

Comment: Every computer I have bought, I have compared with a Mac to see if that has held true, and it has. I have a Core I7 laptop, with a nvidia graphics card (forget the model number off hand) with 8gb of ram and a tb hard drive. At the time (a few years ago) this cost me about $1100. The best price I could find on a mac that was comparable was $1950. My Ultrabook I got about 2 years ago (an Asus Zenbook) was about $1000 at the time, the Airs I looked at started at $1500 and they were less powerful than the Asus (the Zenbook is just as thin as the air if not thiner)